# How to understand "When we aren't looking for pictures of kittens"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

[Source](http://php.net/archive/2014.php#id2014-05-27-1):

> When we aren't looking for pictures of kittens on the internet,
>   internals developers are nearly always looking for ways to improve
>   PHP, a few developers have a focus on performance.

How to understand "When we aren't looking for pictures of kittens" here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a widely shared semi-serious belief that most people use the internet for trivial purposes, e.g. to view pictures of kittens. The writer is making a "joke".

[Cats and the Internet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cats_and_the_Internet)

Comment: Or, more to the point, *when we aren't busy doing something else (such as looking for pictures of kittens)*.